# Forecast when the time series is not sequential?

Tags: r, time-series, neural-networks, forecasting, keras

I have multivariate time series data consisting of monthly sales of contraceptives at various delivery sites in a certain country, between January 2016 and June 2019. The data looks as follows:

[image]

The task in hand is to predict the average monthly sales (`stock_distributed`) for July, August and September (row `month`) for 2019. However, the data is not a multivariate time series data (not sequential), and the predicted results should fit in this table:

[image]

As you can see the predictions are based on combinations of different explanatory variables. My question is: what is the most appropriate deep learning method that would allow me to predict the monthly sales as combinations of the four explanatory variables?

Comment: Can you explain the meaning of *time series is not sequential*?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Thanks for reaching out. The data is a cross-sectional data captured at different time periods. You can check this question here, it is very close to my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40008240/how-to-process-panel-data-for-use-in-a-recurrent-neural-network-rnn